# Finding what month it is based on the number of the week in a year

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to store daily/weekly/monthly data.

Every day a function executes and collects all the logs from that day and stores them into a weekly node with moments **.isoWeek()** method to determine what week of the year it is.

[image: database]

Now i need to find out what month it is based on the information i have(provided in the screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the year, you can chain moment segments together:

```
const monthNumber = moment().isoWeekYear(2019).isoWeekday(1).isoWeek(10).month();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there's an exact (simple) calculation to work this out - according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date);

> The ISO standard does not define any association of weeks to months. A
>   date is either expressed with a month and day-of-the-month, or with a
>   week and day-of-the-week, never a mix.

Alternatively, this leaves us with a calculating a rough estimation. For example;

```
# Divide the week number by an average approximation of weeks within a month

Week 29 / 4.1 = 7 # This gives us july
```